# ACE.exe is not a valid Win32 Application

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have an application compiled using MS Visual Studio 2017. The application is a C++ application using MFC. 
When the application is tried to run on Windows Server 2003 R2, I get this error

> ACE.exe is not a valid Win32 Application.

The command `set processor` returns following

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64

PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=EM64T Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel 

PROCESSOR_LEVEL =6

PROCESSOR_REVISION=2d02
```

The server is running on a VM.

Does any one have any idea why it might not be running?

Comment: Does the executable run on the machine you compiled it on?

Comment: yes mate, It runs fine.

Comment: Have you tried opening up the exe in a hex editor on the vm and making sure it is what you think it is?  It sounds malformed as you aren't even getting to the DLLs getting loaded.  I often use [cff explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) because it is both awesome and free.  If you are compiling 32bit, try 64bit or visa versa.

Comment: I have verified the size and checksum. I will try this cff explorer. Thanks

Comment: What was the platform toolset value set to in the project general config?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Hi, I have found the reason behind the problem. The executables built by Visual Studio 2017 cannot run on Windows Server 2003 by default.     Following link explains that behaviour
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f699eb18-4090-479c-a2ac-a3c68bc46549/vs-2017-build-x86-for-2003-r2-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application?forum=vcgeneral
I am planning to not support Windows server 2003.